# C#.NET connection string cannot connect

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using Visual C# Express 2008 and created a database and dataset by going to Add->New Data Source. I'm trying to add a record to it but cannot connect using the data string provided in the wizard. Please help. Here is my code

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\myLife.sdf;Password=*******");

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT profiles (profile, file) VALUES ('here', 'here')";
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: What is the error?  Is the database file present?  Is it in the correct location?  Is it writable by the applicable user context?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Compact Edition database file (.sdf) you should use Sql**Ce**Connection instead of SqlConnection as explained in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109696/cant-connect-to-my-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you need to specify the username and the password in the same connection string.  I know that you can use your windows credentials to connect by using `integrated security=true` in the connection string, but I think that in your case, you probably want to use `Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\myLife.sdf;User id=Bob;Password=*******`

Comment: A good site for building your connection strings is... http://connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I'm not sure that SQL Server CE supports user-level logon security, but, I believe, the DB itself can be password protected.