# Can't connect to my SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I'm creating a very basic CRUD desktop winforms application in C#/.NET 4.0.

Letting Visual Studio auto-generate the fields for the table I'd like to perform my CRUD operations on works just fine, but I'm running into problems when I try and interact with it manually with my own SQL queries.

The auto-generated fields are using the connection string:

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Data Analysis.sdf
```

If I try and do:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Data Analysis.sdf");
conn.Open();
```

It just hangs. What am I missing?

Comment: Your connection string seems to be wrong.Please use standard format of connection string.

Comment: @ShoaibMuhammadKhan - When I try and run the application now, I don't get any exceptions, it just completely crashes. The first time I tried it however, it said something along the lines of "Could not connect", no more information than that, really.

Comment: @marc_s - I presume it is - well, it must be if it's working for Visual Studio's auto-generated controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a connection string for a SQL Server **Compact Edition** (CE) database (everything stored inside a single `.sdf` file) - is that what you're using?

If so : in that case, you'd have to use `SqlCeConnection` (not a `SqlConnection` - that's for "grown-up" SQL Server version - not CE)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding some more options to the connection string:

```
Persist Security Info=False;
File Mode=shared read;
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe you've specified a relative path to the .sdf file, where you might need to get the executable's runtime folder from System.Environment.CurrentDirectory and prepend it to the filename.